# Build OpenCascade for VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, opencascade

**Usecase:** I intend to use the OpenCascade C++ library in my C++ project. I need to do simple polyline offsetting and polygon scaling down.

So I am attempting to install the OpenCascade C++ library on my Windows 10 64bit machine to use in Visual Studio 17. My first attempt was to use the windows installer then run the batch files (env.bat, custom.bat). But I have [read on this forum](http://www.opencascade.com/content/build-samples-windows) that the windows installer wont work for Visual Studio 2017 - is that correct?

So I have now followed the build instructions [here](http://dev.opencascade.org/doc/overview/html/occt_dev_guides__building_msvc.html#build_msvc_conf). And now I have opened the sample projects in Visual Studio 2017. When I try to build the project I get the following errors for each of the sample projects:

> Error    MSB8036    The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution".    TKQADraw    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v141\Toolset.targets    36

Any advice on what I have done wrong? Maybe I didn't build it properly following [these steps](http://dev.opencascade.org/doc/overview/html/occt_dev_guides__building_msvc.html#build_msvc_conf)? Also, given my usecase above, do I need to do all this if I just want to use OpenCascade in a limited way?

Is there documentation or a link on how I create a new Visual Studio C++ project and link all the OpenCascade libraries?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you haven't installed the correct SDK version, or maybe the version you installed is out dated. Check the SDK install and try again.